# Why am I getting a "no module named urls" error for django rest framework swagger?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, python-import

From my **urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    url(r'^docs/', include('rest_framework_swagger.urls')),
]
```

I recently installed `django_rest_swagger`, and it's included in the INSTALLED_APPS in `settings.py`. However, when I try running the server, I get an `ImportError`:

```
  File "/home/myname/myapp/api/urls.py", line 11, in <module>
    url(r'^docs/', include('rest_framework_swagger.urls')),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 52, \
in include
urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named urls
```

I am using a custom user auth model and token authentication, which may or may not be affecting this (I have been unable to use the browsable API, as well).

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1,default='')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,default='')
```

---

Additionally, when I tried implementing a schema view, I got this separate error:

**views.py**:

```
@api_view()
@renderer_classes([SwaggerUIRenderer, OpenAPIRenderer])
def schema_view(request):
    generator = schemas.SchemaGenerator(title='Test API')
    return Response(generator.get_schema(request=request))
```

**urls.py**:

urlpatterns= [
    ...,
    url(r'schema-view/',schema_view),
    ...,
]

```
AttributeError at /schema-view/

'ObtainAuthToken' object has no attribute 'get_serializer_class'
```

This code I copy/pasted from a tutorial, but it doesn't make sense why it doesn't work, but it seems related to the fact that `get_serializer_class()` is not explicitly defined for a view class that only inherits from `APIView`, which is the case of the `ObtainAuthToken` class.  I've been having much difficulty tracking class methods due to metaclass usage built into the rest framework, though, so I cannot be sure.

My end goal is to get documentation for an API that I am programming, but eveyr single attempt seems to throw a different issue at me. Is there something here that I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 5):

for Django > 1.10  project urls.py

```
from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view
schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='API name')
from django.urls import path
urlpatterns = [
    path('', schema_view)
]  

urlpatterns += [
# your patterns here
]
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue is because of django-rest-swagger version. Try to install swagger 0.3.5 version using pip install django-rest-swagger===0.3.5  with django 1.9. If you django version is 1.10, then follow the link below to solve the issue https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/452